# Ошибка при импорте из dump в разных версиях mysql

Tags: mysql, mariadb, dump, импорт

На моем рабочем ПК стоит **Server version: 10.1.14-MariaDB MariaDB Server**

У брата: 
**mysql Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.49, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 6.3**

У него не получается сделать импорт из моего дампа.
У меня же все без проблем импортируются, кодировки везде utf-8. 
Ниже лог ошибок:

```
mysql -uroot -p1111 -f pogladenota < ~/Рабочий\ стол/pogladenota_dump2.sql
```

ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 135: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(6) DEFAULT NULL,
`is_superuser` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
`username` varchar(30)' at line 4
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 156: Table 'pogladenota.auth_user' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 157: Table 'pogladenota.auth_user' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 158: Table 'pogladenota.auth_user' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 159: Table 'pogladenota.auth_user' doesn't exist
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 226: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(6) NOT NULL,
`object_id` longtext,
`object_repr` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
`' at line 3
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 247: Table 'pogladenota.django_admin_log' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 248: Table 'pogladenota.django_admin_log' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 249: Table 'pogladenota.django_admin_log' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 250: Table 'pogladenota.django_admin_log' doesn't exist
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 286: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(6) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=77 DEFAULT CHA' at line 5
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 299: Table 'pogladenota.django_migrations' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 300: Table 'pogladenota.django_migrations' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 301: Table 'pogladenota.django_migrations' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 302: Table 'pogladenota.django_migrations' doesn't exist
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 312: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(6) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`session_key`),
KEY`django_session_de54fa62`(`e' at line 4
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 325: Table 'pogladenota.django_session' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 326: Table 'pogladenota.django_session' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 327: Table 'pogladenota.django_session' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 328: Table 'pogladenota.django_session' doesn't exist
(pogladenota) laptop ~/Git/pogladenota $

Можно ли как-то создать дамп, который будет работать и у него? Или с какими флагами ему нужно импортировать?

Answer (score 1):

начнем с самого начала

```
Table 'pogladenota.django_migrations' doesn't exist
Table 'pogladenota.django_admin_log' doesn't exist
Table 'pogladenota.auth_user' doesn't exist
Table 'pogladenota.django_session' doesn't exist
```

говорит что нет таких таблиц в бд pogladenota

далее , идем в PHPMyAdmin заходим в каждую таблицу , идем в Экспорт
нажимаем "Обычный Отображать все возможные настройки"
ищем "структура и данные" (через F3 так будет быстрее) , выберем "Структура"
и делаем дамп , а далее он , через созданный дамп , ручками через вкладку SQL будет вставлять таблицы вручную , для отлова ошибок , все ошибки с *разными версиями* гуглятся и решение находится на 2-3 ссылке 
так же можно сделать все не по таблицам а со всей бд , так быстрее , но я предпочитаю делать дампы отдельно таблиц

Answer (score 0):

С самого начала - это вот тут:

> ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 135: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(6) DEFAULT NULL, is_superuser tinyint(1) NOT NULL, username varchar(30)' at line 4

`MariaDB`, как и `Mysql`, имеют весьма дурацкие сообщения о синтаксических ошибках - они показывают место, после которого парсер не разобрал запрос. Ошибка почти всегда в предыдущей лексеме. Соответственно, посмотрите, что написано в похожем месте дампа, судя по всему это какой-то `create table`, поищите его по видимым в ошибке другим полям.

Несколько следующих table not exists больше похожи на прямое следствие этой ошибки, чем на отдельные проблемы, следовательно, проблема в экспорте самого определения таблицы `auth_user`. Затем ещё пара синтаксических ошибок, и, очевидно, их следствия в виде отсутствующих таблиц.